# Destroy many_to_many relationships Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails

In my `groups` controller I call `usergroups` which has the following Schema.

```
create_table "usergroups", force: :cascade, options: "ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8" do |t|
  t.bigint "user_id"
  t.bigint "group_id"
  t.datetime "created_at", null: false
  t.datetime "updated_at", null: false
  t.index ["group_id"], name: "index_usergroups_on_group_id"
  t.index ["user_id"], name: "index_usergroups_on_user_id"
end
```

I want to destroy one of the `usergroup` records in the `groups` controller. How can I do this? I tried the following code but got this error:

`undefined method 'usergroup'`

This is in the in `show.html.erb` in the Groups view file.

```
<%= link_to 'Remove', usergroup(group_id: @group), method: :delete, data: { confirm: 'Are you sure?' } %>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to create a controller action to destroy all the records.

show.html.erb

```
<%= link_to 'Remove', {controller: "groups", action: "delete_usergroups",
group_id: group}, data: { confirm: 'Are you sure?' } %>
```

groups_controller.rb

```
def delete_usergroups
  Usergroup.where(group_id: params[:id]).delete_all
  redirect_to groups_path
end
```

routes.rb

```
get 'groups/delete_usergroups/:id', to: 'groups#delete_usergroups'
```

Comment: I fixed the routes to add :id, added the redirect in the delete_usergroups method, and fixed the link_to to include the id.